# Kohana set sessions and database

Tags: php, orm, kohana

i'm creating a small shopping cart and i'm saving my products in a session (no database). My session sets the product id. But how can get the correct product from my database that matches the product id in my stored session?

Code:

```
foreach ( (isset($shopcart) && is_array($shopcart) && count($shopcart) > 0) ? $shopcart : array() as $item )
{  
    $this->template->shopcart =  $shopcart;
}
```

.

```
<?php if( isset( $shopcart ) ): ?>
            <?php foreach ($shopcart as $item): ?>
             <?php echo $item['id'] ?>
  <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

EDIT:

```
 foreach ( (isset($shopcart) && is_array($shopcart) && count($shopcart) > 0) ? $shopcart : array() as $item )
    {  
        $this->template->shopcart  = DB::select()->where('id', 'IN', $item['id']) ->from('products')->execute();

        //$this->template->shopcart =  $shopcart;
    }
```

Database_Exception [ 1064 ]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''5'' at line 1 [ SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id` IN '5' ]

EDIT 2:

```
$this->template->shopcart = array();

if (count($shopcart))
{
  $this->template->shopcart = 
    DB::select()
    ->where('id', 'IN', $item)
    ->from('products')
    ->execute();
}
```

Template:

```
<?php if( isset( $shopcart ) ): ?>
  <?php foreach ($shopcart as $item): ?>
<?php echo $item['id'] ?> //This is the product id in my saved session but i need to get the name from the database


 <?php endforeach ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What kind of problem do you have? Cant get ids from session? Or products from DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using ORM or the query builder? If you are using the ORM, you could do:

```php
$this->template->shopcart = 
    ORM::factory('products')
    ->where('id', 'IN', $_SESSION['cart'])
    ->find_all();
```

if you are using the query builder:

```php
$this->template->shopcart = 
     DB::select()
     ->where('id', 'IN', $_SESSION['cart'])
     ->from('products')
     ->execute();
```

In your view, now iterate of your `$shopcart` as you would.

Using your case, (take it out of your loop)

```php
$this->template->shopcart = array();

if (count($shopcart))
{
  $product_ids = array();
  foreach ($shopcart as $item)
  {
     $product_ids[] = $item['id'];
  }
  $this->template->shopcart = 
    DB::select()
    ->where('id', 'IN', $product_ids)
    ->from('products')
    ->execute();
}
```

Comment: @pocesare thanks but is giving me this error `Database_Exception [ 1241 ]: Operand should contain 1 column(s) [ SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id` IN (('5', '1', 'thingy')) ]`

Comment: what is your current code for the query builder? update your question and include it

Comment: I dont know your database table definition, but in your `<?php echo $item['id'] ?>` you should change to `<?php echo $item['name'] ?>`

Comment: whats the content of your `$shopcart` variable? is it like `array(array('id' => 1), array('id' => 2))`? if thats the case, you should change it to be `array(1, 2)` then it will "just work"

Comment: thanks it works! But do you also know a way to ''select'' my session? Now i not can access the stored session like 'count' in my array. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Frenck why dont you group items by ID in shopcart? This way you can store cart as array($id => $count) instead of array(array($id, $count)).

Comment: @biakaveron users can select a number of products, this number i save in a session 'count' now i need to print out the 'count' by the product.

Comment: @pocesar and by the way with the code, if i add the product multiple times is only shows the last one? How does that come?

Comment: @Frenck Just add new count to previous value. Whats the reason of storing the same items in separated rows?

Comment: like @biakaveron said, it's best to increment the count, instead of adding them without an identification.